# Flutter: How to put focus to an autocomplete field?

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, focus

how to put focus to the autocomplete field like it is correctly working with a standard TextField?

Following example can be directly started. Activating *edit* focuses TextField and opens soft-keyboard as expected. Activating *search* opens the search field in AppBar but does NOT focus it.

The real page is quite more complex, so *autofocus* is not an option.

```
/// Flutter code sample for RawAutocomplete
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AutocompleteExampleApp());

class AutocompleteExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutocompleteExampleApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  bool _editActive = false, _searchActive = false;
  String? _autocompleteSelection;
  String _textValue = '';
  FocusNode _searchNode = FocusNode(debugLabel: 'SearchField'),
      _editNode = FocusNode(debugLabel: 'EditField');
  List<String> _resultList = [];
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController(),
      _editingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _editActive
          ? _buildAppBarEdit()
          : _searchActive
              ? _buildAppBarSearch()
              : _buildAppBar(),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _editingController.dispose();
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('Focusing Autocomplete Problem'),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            _searchActive = true;
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_searchNode);
          }),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            _editActive = true;
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_editNode);
          }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBarEdit() {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('Editing Mode'),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.done),
          onPressed: () {
            showInfo(context, 'Edit result = "$_textValue"');
            setState(() => _editActive = false);
          },
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => _editActive = false),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBarSearch() {
    return AppBar(
      title: _buildSearchField(),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.done),
          onPressed: () => _onSearch(),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => _searchActive = false),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        _editActive
            ? TextField(
                controller: _editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Some Value'),
                focusNode: _editNode,
                onChanged: (v) => _textValue = v,
              )
            : Text(_textValue),
        _resultList.isEmpty
            ? Center(
                child: Text('No results'),
              )
            : Column(
                children: _resultList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
              ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _onSearch() {
    showInfo(context, 'Searching for "$_autocompleteSelection"');
    setState(() => _searchActive = false);
  }

  static const List<String> _options = <String>[
    'Coca Cola',
    'Cocoribe',
    'Rum',
    'Malibu',
    'Ron Zacapa',
  ];

  Widget _buildSearchField() {
    return RawAutocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        return _options.where((String option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      onSelected: (String selection) {
        setState(() {
          _autocompleteSelection = selection;
        });
        _onSearch();
      },
      focusNode: _searchNode,
      textEditingController: _searchController,
      fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          TextEditingController textEditingController,
          FocusNode focusNode,
          VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
        return TextField(
          controller: textEditingController,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: '<enter searchtext here>',
          ),
          focusNode: focusNode,
          onSubmitted: (String value) => onFieldSubmitted(),
        );
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected, Iterable<String> options) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Material(
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                itemCount: options.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final String option = options.elementAt(index);
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      onSelected(option);
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(option),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

ScaffoldFeatureController<SnackBar, SnackBarClosedReason> showInfo(
    BuildContext context, String message) {
  return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: '<OK>',
      onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar(),
      textColor: Colors.orange,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade100,
    content: Text(
      message,
//        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      softWrap: true,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  ));
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with my form with loads of autocomplete textfields ...
If I set autocomplete textfields'focus to focusNde and then the autocomplete service will work but it can't catch the primary focus.
If I set autocomplete textield's focus to focusNode which is a focusNode outside the autocomplete widget then it will get the focus but the autocomplete options will not fire on user interaction!
This is a bug I think because I have checked and the texfield got the primary focus but autocomp will not pop the option at the end.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Since you already have a FocusNode variable, just set it to the fieldViewBuilder's focusNode parameter.

```
late FocusNode myFocusNode; //Just one way of initializing a focus node. There are also other ways.

Autocomplete<String>( 
    ... // This represent the rest of your code
    fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context, TextEditingController controller, FocusNode focusNode, VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
        myFocusNode = focusNode; // Assign your focus node to this builder's focus node
        return ...; // And here, to point out the answer.
    }
)
```

Comment: This feels like a terrible solutions, but is the only thing that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a FocusNode, then put a 'blank' Focus widget before the widget you want to focus, request focus to that widget, then automatically pass it to the next focus node (your desired focus).

```
Focus(
  focusNode: focusNodePlaceholder,
    onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
      if (hasFocus) {
        FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
      }
    },
    child: Container(),
),
```

Comment: Not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

As you all know, autocomplete package has it's own textController and focusNode which are passing to the RawAutocomplete.

The problem source is that if you pass the TextField's FocusNode to the autocomplete then it will not get the primary focus node and if you pass the autocomplete focus node to the TextField (which is defining by the package not yours) then the autocomplete will not catch the primaryFocus to provide options as we expected.

One way to put primaryFocus to autocomplete TextField is to define a temporary FocusNode and pass it to the TextField we have been designed inside our autocomplete and pass the focus node programmatically, as you wished to, and inside the `onChanged()` function of the TextField we can put the primaryFocus of our app on the autocomplete's TextField widget.
Please follow the below example:

```
Autocomplete<String>(

      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
        }

        return items.where((String options) => options.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase())).toList();
      },
      onSelected: (value) {
        textController.text = value;
      },

      fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context, txtCTRL, focusNod, onFieldSubmitted) {
        FocusNode focus = focusNode; //focusNode is one we can pass to get the focus programmatically.
              TextFormField(
                           
                focusNode: focus,
                onEditingComplete: () {
                  if (nextFocus != null) {
                    focusNode.unfocus();  //focusNode is one we have used to pass the primaryFocus to the textfield inside our code.
                    nextFocus.requestFocus(); //nextFocus of the list we want to put the focus on submit
                  }
                },
                onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                txtController.text=value;
                focus = focusNod;//pass the autocomplete's focusNode to the temporary focusNode holder (focus).
                focus.requestFocus();
                )}
                },
...
```

This code sample is not complete, but it will show how to pass the primary focus to the autocomplete's TextField widget.

Hope it works for you.